# Can not get jQuery to load on a MAMP server

Tags: jquery, mamp

I have a local MAMP server running on my Mac. I can get css and plain vanilla javascript to run in this environment, but jQuery throws an error.

Here is my html (file name is jqtest.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>

<script src="/js/myscripts.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1> Hello World</h1>
<div class='test'>
Testing <br>
testing <br> 
testing <br>
</div>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

My file structure: 
edweb  
\jqtest.html  
\css\style.css  
\js\myscripts.js  
\js\jquery-1.11.2.js

Any styles I define in css\style work.
Any jscript I put into js\myscripts.js work.

From the console I get the following errors:

```
GET http://localed:8888/js/jquery-1.11.2.js 
jqtest.html:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Comment: Does the jquery file load properly, no 404 errors in console or network panel …?

Comment: Sounds like jQuery is either missing or has the can't be read.

Comment: There are no 404 errors and I downloaded multiple versions of jQuery to the directory. As  a test I created a javascript file that simply popped up a "Hello World" alert message in the same directory. It worked. From jquery.com/download I downloaded compressed and uncompressed versions of 2.1.3 and 1.11.2 making sure to account for the version number and the "min" in the name. I've also tried to recreate my Mamp in a different directory and nothing works yet.

Comment: Ah hah! I checked the Network panel and while the js directory was read only the individual  downloaded js FILE (1.11.2 and 2.1.3) were set to "No Access." You need to change this to at least "read Only" from Get info (on a Mac) or a chmod command.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing my file and folder(directory) permissions. When you download files directly from jQuery.Com they are set as No Access for Everyone. They need to be modified to Read Only.